# DropDownMenu with icon flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

New in flutter. Want to build the drop-down menu list with icon.
Doesn't show any error but stop emulator. Please help me to build like this.

[![Click here to see image][2]][2]
[![Error in Exceptions][1]][1]

```dart
    const catagoryItem = [
    CatagoryItem(name: 'Crypto', iconPath: 'assets/icons/crytoicon.png'),
    CatagoryItem(name: 'Crypto', iconPath: 'assets/icons/crytoicon.png'),
    CatagoryItem(name: 'Crypto', iconPath: 'assets/icons/crytoicon.png'),
    CatagoryItem(name: 'Crypto', iconPath: 'assets/icons/crytoicon.png'),
  ];

 //..
      DropdownButton(items: catagoryItem.map((e) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 5.h,
                width: 6.w,
                child: Image.asset(e.iconPath),),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 2.w,
                ),
                Text(e.name,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.sp),),

            ],

        ))).toList(), onChanged: null)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/toPZp.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2V6A.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (without the flutter_screenutil stuff), it works fine.

I suggest you start by removing those and see if it works, i.e. change `width: 2.w` to something like `width: 8` and whatnot. Also try completely stopping the debug process and restart again, because it might be a hot reload issue too.

Comment: widget.items!.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) => item.value == widget.value).length == 1

showes in exception. I tried with close and restart the emulator . Also flutter clean but same result. I tried as you say but same result doesn't work.